# Run nose2 with coverage for installed package

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, jenkins, code-coverage, nose2

I got some of our project packages installed in a `venv` by a jenkins job. After installing, the job pulls some unittests from a separate repository and runs them against the installed package.

My problem is `coverage` only covers the test scripts but not the installed packages.

Here's the folder structure:

```
JenkinsWorkspace
|_Venv
|_MyProject
  |_trunk
    |_Python   
    |_Package1
    |_Package2
      |_temp_tests
        |_test_suite1.py
        |_...
```

So for further explanation, I iterate over the packages in `MyProject`, checkout the tests for each one into `temp_tests`, `cd` in `temp_tests` and call `nose2 -t ..\..\..\Venv\Lib\site-packages`

I thought the `-t` param would set the top level directory, and use the stuff installed there. And yes, the tests run succesfully. But the `coverage` only covers the test suites themselves.
Is there a way to tell nose to do the coverage for the installed package?

For completeness here my `unittest.cfg`:

```
[coverage]
coverage-report = term-missing
always-on = True
coverage-config = .coveragerc

[junit-xml]
always-on = True
keep_restricted = False
path = nose2-junit.xml
test_fullname = False
```

and `.coveragerc`:

```
# .coveragerc
[run]
branch = True
[report]
show_missing = True
omit = 
    build/*
    tests/*
    setup.py
    */__init__.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by using the `coverage` package after testing.

I did:

```
nose2 --plugin nose2.plugins.junitxml -s tests -c unittest.cfg
python -m coverage xml
```

where the folder `tests` is containing my tests.

My `unittest.cfg` is set to:

```
[coverage]
coverage-report = term-missing
always-on = True
coverage-config = .coveragerc

[junit-xml]
always-on = True
keep_restricted = False
path = nose2-junit.xml
test_fullname = False
```

And in `.coveragerc` I excluded all unwanted (system) packages:

```
# .coveragerc
[run]
branch = True
[report]
show_missing = True
omit = 
    build/*
    tests/*
    setup.py
    */__init__.py
    */nose/*
    */pkg_resources/*
    */six.py
    */nose2/*
    */coverage/*
    */cov_core.py
```

Answer (score 0):

The coverage plugin of nose2 provides an option to define the PATH where to measure coverage, `--coverage PATH`. PATH will accept multiple directories in the usual shell syntax. I suggest this command line:

```
nose2 -t ..\..\..\Venv\Lib\site-packages --coverage ..\..\..\Venv\Lib\site-packages
```

Comment: Note that's just a guess since I don't have nose2 and Linux ready right now. Let me know how it works.